# Small vertical vibrations of a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

The following problem was posed by George Stokes in 1854:

> A rod is suspended at two given points by unequal light elastic
> strings, in such a manner that the rod is horizontal and the strings
> are vertical in the position of equilibrium; the rod being slightly
> disturbed in a vertical plane, in such a manner that no displacement
> of velocity is communicated to the centre of gravity in a horizontal
> direction, it is required to determine the motion.

What is the best way to model/think about this problem?

A simplistic interpretation is to just replace the 2 strings with 2 springs and assume the rod vibrates vertically while staying always horizontal.

A more general interpretation assumes the rod besides vibrating can rotate since the elastic strings are of unequal length. That is a lot harder to model.

Comment: Is it really "displacement of velocity " or it's a typo?

Comment: @nasu Yes it says "displacement of velocity" (it is old english)